# ActiveAdmin: gem not checkout, run bundle install first

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, activeadmin

In a Rails 4 app, I am trying to use ActiveAdmin 1.0.pre2. bundle install doesn't complain and seems to have included the gem and it works properly.

I am having this in my gem file:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'

$> bundle show activeadmin
/home/aslam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@monaeo/bundler/gems/active_admin-3fb7f03335b1
```

Even after running bundle install several times, I keep getting the following error:

```
git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git (at master) is not yet checked out.
Run `bundle install` first.
```

I am using

- Bundler version 1.6.0.rc2 (upgraded from 1.5.3)
- Ruby: ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [i686-linux]
- Rails: 4.0.4

I am not sure what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install a prerelease version of Bundler:

```
gem install bundler --pre
```

It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use following in the Gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin', :git => "git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git"
```

This way when you run `bundle install`, `activeadmin` would be sourced from its github repository.

Answer (score 0):

Two things

A. You need to include like this in the gem file since `0.6.x` is stable and maintained.

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: '0-6-stable'
```

B. You can give a try by forking from the stable version of activeadmin

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
rake rails:update:bin
bundle install
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.